# sliding panel open/close on click

Tags: jquery, click, mouseover

How can I have have this sliding panel function but "on click" instead of mouseover/mouseout

```
    <script>
    $("button.main").mouseover(function() {
        $("div.sliderInner").animate(
                {"width": "100px"},
                "500");
    });

    $("button.main").mouseout(function() {
        $("div.sliderInner").animate(
                {"width": "0px"},
                "700");
    });

    $("button.main").mouseover(function() {
       $("div.sliderInner")
      .html('Example Content');
    });

    $("button.main").mouseout(function() {
       $("div.sliderInner")
      .html('');
    });
    </script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Ohh no you forget to wrap code inside `document.ready`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mouseover do .toggle and then supply any number of functions you want it to toggle through including slideInner

```
 $(#buttonmain).toggle(function () {
     $('div.sliderInner').animate(
            {"width": "100px"},
             "500");
       }, function () {
          //animate next click
       });
```

The clicks will cycle through your functions